# MVC 4 _Layout.cshtml viewmodel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to display a count of selected items on every page in my MVC site. I have a ViewModel that defines the properties I want there

```
public class CartViewModel
{
    public List<CartItem> CartItems { get; set; }
    public decimal CartTotal { get; set; }
}
```

a controller that gets the Cart, maps it to the view model and passes that on

```
public ActionResult GetCartSummary()
{
    var cart = Cart.Instance;
    var viewModel = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Cart, CartViewModel>(cart);
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

and a view for that

```
@model TheWorkshop.Web.Models.Edit.ShoppingCartViewModel

<h2>Cart Summary</h2>
<span>@Model.CartTotal</span>
```

and finally in my `_Layout.cshtml` file

```
@Html.Action("GetCartSummary", "Cart")
```

But this gives me

> System.StackOverflowException was unhandled

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding the following to your cart view:

```
@{Layout = null;}
```

Comment: This works nicely; would never have guessed it was the recursing views

Answer (score 3):

Try returning a PartialView instead of View:

```
public ActionResult GetCartSummary()
{
    var cart = Cart.Instance;
    var viewModel = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Cart, CartViewModel>(cart);
    return PartialView(viewModel);
}
```

Comment: This will work as well because `PartialView` implicitly sets `Layout = null`.

Comment: Someone told me only use a partial view if you need to use it elsewhere. Is this a recommended approach?

Comment: You use a PartialView anytime you are nesting a view in another view, because otherwise, you will get all of your layout stuff surrounding where the view is nested.  I.e. your header Menus/LOGO will be duplicated and it will look terrible.

Comment: Maybe they were thinking of shared views.  I keep my View and PartialViews for a controller in the same folder.  Except when the PartialView is going to be used elsewhere, then in that case I put them in the Shared Views folder.